# Couldn't read row 0, col 9 from CursorWindow

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, cursor

I'm getting the error Couldn't read row 0, col 9 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.  Two other people are able to run the code without error but on my machine it throws it.  I'm very confused. Here is the code that deals with the SQLite:
Thanks in advance, sorry there's a lot of code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class FeedSQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

//Table Name
public static final String TABLE_POSTS = "comments";

//Table Column names
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_CAPTION = "caption";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME= "name";
public static final String COLUMN_LIKE="like";
public static final String COLUMN_DISLIKE="dislike";
public static final String COLUMN_COMMENTS = "columns";
public static final String COLUMN_ALL_COMMENTS = "allComments";
public static final String COLUMN_PHOTO = "photo";
public static final String COLUMN_CELEB = "celeb";
public static final String COLUMN_FID = "facebook_id";
public static final String COLUMN_TIME = "timestamp";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "commments.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 6;

// Database creation sql statement
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
  + TABLE_POSTS + "(" + COLUMN_ID
  + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_CAPTION
  + " text not null, " + COLUMN_NAME + " text not null, " 
  + COLUMN_LIKE + " integer not null, " + COLUMN_DISLIKE + " integer not null, "
  + COLUMN_COMMENTS + " integer not null, " + COLUMN_ALL_COMMENTS + " text, " 
  + COLUMN_PHOTO + " text, " + COLUMN_FID + " text, " + COLUMN_TIME + " long);";

public FeedSQLiteHelper(Context context) {
super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
Log.w(FeedSQLiteHelper.class.getName(),
    "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
        + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
if(oldVersion <6) {
    final String ALTER_TBL = "ALTER TABLE " + TABLE_POSTS + " ADD COLUMN " + COLUMN_TIME     + " long;";
    db.execSQL(ALTER_TBL);
}
}

//Adding new contact
public void addContact(FeedsModel contact) {
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(COLUMN_NAME, contact.getName());
values.put(COLUMN_CAPTION, contact.getDesc());
values.put(COLUMN_LIKE, contact.getUps());
values.put(COLUMN_DISLIKE, contact.getDowns());
values.put(COLUMN_COMMENTS, contact.getComments());
values.put(COLUMN_ALL_COMMENTS, contact.getAllComments());
values.put(COLUMN_PHOTO, contact.getImageId());
values.put(COLUMN_FID, contact.getFID());
values.put(COLUMN_TIME, contact.getTimestamp());

// Inserting Row
db.insert(TABLE_POSTS, null, values);
db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

//Getting single contact
public FeedsModel getContact(int id) {
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_POSTS, new String[] { COLUMN_ID,
        COLUMN_CAPTION, COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_LIKE, COLUMN_DISLIKE, COLUMN_COMMENTS,      COLUMN_ALL_COMMENTS, COLUMN_PHOTO, COLUMN_FID, COLUMN_TIME }, COLUMN_ID + "=?",
        new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
if (cursor != null)
    cursor.moveToFirst();

FeedsModel contact = new FeedsModel(
        Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), 
        cursor.getString(1), 
        cursor.getString(2), 
        Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3)), 
        Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(4)),
        Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(5)),
        cursor.getString(6),
        cursor.getString(7),
        cursor.getString(8),
        Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(9)));

// return contact
return contact;
}

//filters the news feed for the 'Me' option
public List<FeedsModel> getMe(String me)
{
List<FeedsModel> contactList = new ArrayList<FeedsModel>();

String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_POSTS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_FID + "= "+ me;

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

// looping through all rows and adding to list
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        FeedsModel contact = new FeedsModel();
        contact.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        contact.setDesc(cursor.getString(1));
        contact.setName(cursor.getString(2));
        contact.setUps(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3)));
        contact.setDowns(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(4)));
        contact.setComments(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(5)));
        contact.setAllComments(cursor.getString(6));
        contact.setImageId(cursor.getString(7));
        contact.setFID(cursor.getString(8));
        contact.setTimestamp(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(9)));
        // Adding contact to list
        contactList.add(contact);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}

// return contact list
return contactList;
}

//filters the news feed for the 'Me' option
public List<FeedsModel> getMostRecent()
{
List<FeedsModel> contactList = new ArrayList<FeedsModel>();

String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_POSTS + " ORDER BY " + COLUMN_TIME + " DESC";

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

// looping through all rows and adding to list
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
  do {
      FeedsModel contact = new FeedsModel();
      contact.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
      contact.setDesc(cursor.getString(1));
      contact.setName(cursor.getString(2));
      contact.setUps(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3)));
      contact.setDowns(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(4)));
      contact.setComments(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(5)));
      contact.setAllComments(cursor.getString(6));
      contact.setImageId(cursor.getString(7));
      contact.setFID(cursor.getString(8));
      contact.setTimestamp(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(9)));
      // Adding contact to list
      contactList.add(contact);
  } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}

// return contact list
return contactList;
}

//Getting All Contacts
public List<FeedsModel> getAllContacts() {

List<FeedsModel> contactList = new ArrayList<FeedsModel>();
// Select All Query
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_POSTS;

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

// looping through all rows and adding to list
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        FeedsModel contact = new FeedsModel();
        contact.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        contact.setDesc(cursor.getString(1));
        contact.setName(cursor.getString(2));
        contact.setUps(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3)));
        contact.setDowns(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(4)));
        contact.setComments(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(5)));
        contact.setAllComments(cursor.getString(6));
        contact.setImageId(cursor.getString(7));
        contact.setFID(cursor.getString(8));
        contact.setTimestamp(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(9)));
        // Adding contact to list
        contactList.add(contact);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}

// return contact list
return contactList;

}

//Getting contacts Count
public int getContactsCount() {

String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_POSTS;
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
cursor.close();

// return count
return cursor.getCount();

}
//Updating single contact
public int updateContact(FeedsModel contact) {

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(COLUMN_NAME, contact.getName());
values.put(COLUMN_CAPTION, contact.getDesc());
values.put(COLUMN_LIKE, contact.getUps());
values.put(COLUMN_DISLIKE, contact.getDowns());
values.put(COLUMN_COMMENTS, contact.getComments());
values.put(COLUMN_ALL_COMMENTS, contact.getAllComments());
values.put(COLUMN_PHOTO, contact.getImageId());
values.put(COLUMN_FID, contact.getFID());
values.put(COLUMN_TIME, contact.getTimestamp());

// updating row
return db.update(TABLE_POSTS, values, COLUMN_ID + " = ?",
        new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getId()) });

}

//Deleting single contact
public void deleteContact(FeedsModel contact) {

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
db.delete(TABLE_POSTS, COLUMN_ID + " = ?",
        new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getId()) });
db.close();

}

}
```

Logcat:

```
E/CursorWindow(841): Failed to read row 0, column 9 from a CursorWindow which has 3 rows, 9 columns.
D/AndroidRuntime(841): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(841): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
E/AndroidRuntime(841): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(841): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{edu.Drake.doppelganger/edu.Drake.doppelganger.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 9 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(841): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 9 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:434)
E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at edu.Drake.doppelganger.FeedSQLiteHelper.getAllContacts(FeedSQLiteHelper.java:198)
E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at edu.Drake.doppelganger.FeedFragment.onActivityCreated(FeedFragment.java:65)
E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1703)
E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:903)
E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5113)
E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2153)
E/AndroidRuntime(841):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: post your logcat trace.

Answer (score 3):

it is because you try to get the data before checking their is data available or not.

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        // your content
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Change this block to

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        // your content
}
```

Like this.

Surely this will help you.