# how to store string data into integer array from sqlite for android

Tags: java, android, arrays

I want to convert the sqlite data into integer array.

```
public Integer[] getch() {

        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT sum(sales) FROM sales group by outlet_code order by ordered_date", null);
        // String[] array = new String[crs.getCount()];
        int columnIndex = 3;
        Integer[] in = new Integer[cursor.getCount()];

        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++)
            {
                in[i] = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
        return in;
    }
```

I need result in following format:

```
int[] income = { 2000,2500,2700,3000,2800,3500,3700,3800, 0,0,0,0};

Integer[] income =  controller.getch();
```

I'm getting the error :

> Couldn't read row 0, col 3 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is
>   initialized correctly before accessing data from it

Comment: `in[i] = cursor.getInt(0);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Couldn't read row 0, col 9 from CursorWindow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16497969/couldnt-read-row-0-col-9-from-cursorwindow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `columnIndex = 3`, your sql query will return only 1 column i.e `Sum(sales)`, so you should set your `columnIndex` value to `0`

Try this

```
public Integer[] getch() {

    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT sum(sales) FROM sales group by outlet_code order by ordered_date", null);
    // String[] array = new String[crs.getCount()];
    int columnIndex = 0;
    Integer[] in = new Integer[cursor.getCount()];

    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++)
        {
            in[i] = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
    return in;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: then please mark it correct/accept the answer by taping 'right mark' icon next to Answer. Thanks